# Plotting geom_point() on top of geom_hex() in ggplot2()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a background dataset (below: "bDat") as hexagonal bins, and then overlay points from a different dataset (below: "points"). I would like to accomplish this using `ggplot2()` and keeping the syntax as similar as possible to the MWE provided below.

I am able to get the hexagonal background plotted with the below MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)

set.seed(1)
bDat <- data.frame(Group1 = rnorm(100,0,1), Group2 = rnorm(100,0,1))
points <- data.frame(Group1 = rnorm(10,0.5,1), Group2 = rnorm(10,0.5,1))
maxVal = max(max(bDat), max(points))
minVal = min(min(bDat), min(points))
maxRange = c(minVal, maxVal)
xbins=10
buffer = maxRange[2]/xbins
xChar = "Group1"
yChar = "Group2"
x = bDat[,c(xChar)]
y = bDat[,c(yChar)]
h <- hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=xbins, shape=1, IDs=TRUE, xbnds=maxRange, ybnds=maxRange)
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
attr(hexdf, "cID") <- h@cID

ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID)) +
  geom_hex(stat="identity") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]), ylim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]))
```

However, when I change the last command in the above MWE to try to overlay the points, I receive an error that the object hexID is not found:

```
ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID)) +
  geom_hex(stat="identity") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]), ylim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2])) + 
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x=Group1, y=Group2))
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'hexID' not found

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_point`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of the geoms it to inherit the aesthetics already specified in the `ggplot` object.  In your example,

```
ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID))
```

will result, by default, all `geom_*` calls to use these values for the `x`, `y`, `fill`, and `hexID` aesthetics.  This works well when all the layers use the same data set and aesthetics.

However, when `geom_point(data = points, aes(x = Group1, y = Group2))` is called, the `fill = counts` and `hexID = hexID` is implicitly passed to `geom_point` as well.

By seting the `inherit.aes = FALSE` the geom

> overrides the default aesthetics, rather than
>             combining with them. This is most useful for helper functions
>             that define both data and aesthetics and shouldn't inherit
>             behaviour from the default plot specification, e.g. ‘borders’.

From your first MWE, take

```
last_plot() + 
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x=Group1, y=Group2), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

and the resulting plot is:
[image]